# Eclipselink-QueryException on nested join

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have a query to a pretty simple datamodel that throws an `org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException` and i do not understand why.

Here is the setting. I have a datamodel where a `Person` can have one `Address` and many `Job`s. Each job itself can have many `Address`es as well. Each relationship is unidirectional. And each relationship is optional (I can attach sourcecode if necessary).

```
         Person 
         1 / \ 1
          /   \
    0..1 /     \ *
   Address     Job
                 \ 1
                  \
                   \ *
                    Address
```

My goal is to create a list of all addresses with all related jobs and persons. And I want to achieve this with just one database query. In the end I need some datastructure like `Map<Address, Pair<Set<Person>, Set<Job>>>` (where `Pair` is i. e. `org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair`)

So I joined all entities with the criteria api like this.

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery query = builder.createQuery();

Root<Person> personRoot = query.from(Person.class);
Join<Person, Address> joinPersonAddress = personRoot.join(Person_.address, JoinType.LEFT);
Join<Person, Job> joinPersonJob = personRoot.join(Person_.jobs, JoinType.LEFT);
Join<Job, Address> joinJobAddress = joinPersonJob.join(Job_.addresses, JoinType.LEFT);

query.multiselect(personRoot, joinPersonAddress, joinPersonJob, joinJobAddress);
Query q = em.createQuery(query);
List<Object[/*Person, Address, Job, Address*/]> result = q.getResultList();
```

But in the last line I get an exception.

```
Exception [EclipseLink-6044] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The primary key read from the row [DatabaseRecord(
    nullJoin_job.ID => null
    nullJoin_job.JOBNAME => null
    nullJoin_ADDRESS.ID => null
    nullJoin_ADDRESS.CITY => null
    nullJoin_ADDRESS.STREET => null)] during the execution of the query was detected to be null.  Primary keys must not contain null.
Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=Person sql="SELECT t0.ID, t0.PERSON_ID, t1.ID, t1.CITY, t1.STREET, t2.ID, t2.JOBNAME, t3.ID, t3.CITY, t3.STREET FROM nullJoin_person t0 LEFT OUTER JOIN nullJoin_ADDRESS t1 ON (t1.ID = t0.PERSON_ID) LEFT OUTER JOIN nullJoin_job t2 ON (t2.PERSON_ID = t0.ID) LEFT OUTER JOIN nullJoin_ADDRESS t3 ON (t3.JOB_ID = t2.ID)")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.nullPrimaryKeyInBuildingObject(QueryException.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:613)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQueryResult.processItem(ReportQueryResult.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQueryResult.buildResult(ReportQueryResult.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQueryResult.<init>(ReportQueryResult.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQuery.buildObject(ReportQuery.java:593)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQuery.buildObjects(ReportQuery.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ReportQuery.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1114)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1202)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2894)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1797)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1779)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1744)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:468)
    at test.dao.Dao.test(Dao.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ...
    ...
```

I do not understand this exception. If I execute the printed SQL-statement in my database tool it works as a charm.

At the moment I execute two queries, one to join the person with the addresses and another to join the jobs with the addresses. After that I create my `Map<Address, Pair<Set<Person>, Set<Job>>>` in code.

So just for curiosity, why is that exception being thrown respectively is there a way to fix this so that I could end up using just one database query?

Comment: The problem isn't with the query, but with the data returned. When you execute the query yourself what do you get back for the fields it is saying are null?  PKs cannot be null, so the left outer join probably prevents JPA from building the 3 entities your query states JPA must build from the data.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `ObjectBuilder`, an internal class that handles the query result and builds the result object, is not able to handle null results.

You can confirm this by testing the query on a db without null relationships (i.e. without no-address persons and jobs). It should work in these cases.

I suggest to open a bug to eclipselink after trying with other JPA providers.

As a workaround you can build a query that returns a [`Tuple`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Tuple.html) instead of an object:

```
CriteriaQuery query = builder.createQuery(Tuple.class);
...
query.multiselect(personRoot, joinPersonAddress, joinPersonJob, joinJobAddress);
TypedQuery<Tuple> tq = em.createQuery(query);
```